# Problema con los botones de masterPage en demás paginas

Tags: c#, asp.net, botón

En mi master page tengo unos botones que utilizo al estilo de menu en mis paginas, quiero utilizarlos en el resto de las paginas pero no me deja, me dice que el botón, por ej: btnInicio, no existe en el contexto actual. No puedo utilizar ninguno de los botones fuera de la master page. 
Acá el código:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Principal.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="App_Themes/Tema1/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <link href="css/bootstrap (2).css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <style type="text/css">
        .modalBackground {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
            z-index: 10000;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="bg-black-gradient" id="Principal">

            <div id="cabecera-Menu">
                <div id="Logo">
                    <img src="imgs/LogoPeque.png" />
                </div>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <div id="Menu">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnInicio" runat="server" Text="Inicio" CssClass="btn btn-link" OnClick="btnInicio_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCarrito" runat="server" Text="Carrito De Compras" CssClass="btn btn-link" OnClick="btnCarrito_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSingUp" runat="server" Text="Registro" CssClass="btn bg-black-gradient" OnClick="btnSingUp_Click" />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnPopUp" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn bg-black-gradient" />

                    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnPopUp_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
                        DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnPopUp"
                        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="PanelModal">
                    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblWelcomeEmail" runat="server" Text="Bienvenido" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogout" runat="server" OnClick="desloguearse" CssClass="btn bg-black-gradient" Text="Cerrar Sesion" Visible="false" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Bajo">

                <div id="ColumIzq">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MenuContextual" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>

                <div id="ColumnCentro">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContenidoPrincipal" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>

                <div id="ColumnDer" runat="server">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContenidoDerecho" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>


                <div id="Pie">
                    <span>The Bookvie Store </span>
                </div>

            </div>


            <asp:Panel ID="PanelModal" runat="server" Style="display: none; background: white; width: 30%; height: auto">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLogin" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            <h3 id="myModalLabel" class="box-header">Iniciar Sesion</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-fluid well">
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span4">
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" WatermarkText="Email" TargetControlID="txtEmail" />
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" runat="server" WatermarkText="Contraseña" TargetControlID="txtPassw" />
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassw" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="errorDatos" class="control-group">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" Visible="False" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text="Entrar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" Text="Registrarse" runat="server" OnClick="SignUp_Click" CssClass="btn" Font-Bold="True" />
                        </div>

                    </ContentTemplate>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo que agregar / quitar algo para que funcione? Qué estoy haciendo mal? Saludos.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de como tratas de buscar el botón del MasterPage.

Comment: Como cualquier botón, por ej btnInicio.Visible =true ;

Comment: el resto de las paginas estan embebidas sobre la pagina maestra. no deberias estar referenciando la pagina maestra para buscarlos? porque para la pagina hijo, la maestra es solo un contenedor.

Comment: Claaro, lo supuse y estuve buscando pero no logro encontrar con el código correcto. De todos los que probé, ninguno funcionaba.

Comment: @YamilaMarucci ¿De que manera quieres utilizarlas?, por lo que me dices solo quieres manipular su propiedades. O sino tu pregunta debería ser, ¿Cómo buscar un control del Master Page?. `Button btnInicio =  this.Master.FindControl("btnInicio") as Button;`

Comment: @Davlio Eso mismo quería hacer, disculpa por no saber explicarme bien. Ya tengo la cabeza comida por asp.. Gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los controles son protegidos, por lo que sólo los puedes acceder desde la Master o sus derivados. Tienes que hacer una propiedad pública para que sean accesibles desde fuera:

```
public Button BtnInicio
{
    get
    {
        return this.btnInicio;
    }
}
```

O bien, debes buscarlo por nombre:

```
Button btnInicio = Master.FindControl("btnInicio") as Button;
```

Chequea por `null` en caso de que en algún momento el control cambie de nombre. Este problema no lo tienes si utilizas la primera opción.

Más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573505/how-to-access-master-page-control-from-content-page).

Comment: Si mi clase del Master Page se llama `Plantilla` y tiene la propiedad `BtnInicio`, ¿Se tendría que convertir primero `(Plantilla)(this.Master)` para encontrar la propiedad `BtnInicio`?

Comment: Así es, porque `Master` es del tipo `MasterPage`, por lo que sólo tiene las propiedades de la clase base.