# ¿Cómo encontrar un control del Master Page y recuperar su valor en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Cómo encontrar un control del Master Page y recuperar su valor en C#

Saludos

Comment: Tu pregunta más bien debería ser: _"Cómo encontrar un control del Master Page y recuperar su valor"_. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Puedes guiarte de preguntas que existen: [Problema con los botones de masterPage en demás paginas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51010/problema-con-los-botones-de-masterpage-en-dem%C3%A1s-paginas). En tu caso sería para un `Label`.

Comment: Gracias por la observación...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar el `FindControl()` sobre el objeto `Master`:

```
TextBox text1 = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Aquí se explica con más detalles:

[How to: Reference ASP.NET Master Page Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx)

Comment: Gracias Leandro...